# Unresolved reference 'mptt'

Tags: python

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class People(MPTTModel):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    employment_date = models.DateField(max_length=80)
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2)
    settle_up = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['full_name']
```

выдает 3 ошибки
Unresolved reference 'mptt'
Unresolved reference 'MPTTModel'
Unresolved reference 'TreeForeignKey'
не знаю как решить эту проблему

Comment: Убедитесь в правильности названия модуля. Вы уверены, что модуль  называется именно mptt.models? Как-то не встречал модули с точкой в имени:-) И поиском такой стандартный модуль не нашёл.

Comment: да, брала это из документации

Comment: Из какой именно документации? Надо понимать, что это за модуль и как именно он должен быть доступен для интрепретатора Python? Очевидно, что Python его не видит.

Comment: https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

Comment: Тогда с названием модуля все нормально. По логике, что-то не то с подключением. Сам с django  не работаю, но вопрос, а в settings.py вы добавляли mptt? Типа (/=перенос строки, в комментах перенос не сделать): INSTALLED_APPS = (/
    'django.contrib.auth',/
    # .../
    'mptt',/
)

Comment: Да, в settings.py все добавила
понимаю, что какая-то проблема с подключением, но не могу разобраться какая
совместимость проверила, вроде все хорошо

Comment: тогда больше нечего подсказать мне, увы:-(

Comment: вроде как сервер запускается не на моем окружении проекта, может знаете как это исправить?

Comment: Не знаю. Но можете попробовать PyCharm поставить, если вы в IDLE Shell, и оттуда запустить. У меня почему-то print в мультипроцессинге не работал в IDLE Shell, а в PyCharm заработал.